# Python. Сортировка значений ключей словарей которые находятся в кортеже

Tags: python

У меня есть структура из словарей в кортеже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы не меняете свой исходный кортеж. Почитайте про разницу `sorted` и метода `sort`. То есть, сортировка у вас происходит, но нигде не фиксируется.

Попробуйте так:

```
for row in a:
    row['size_measures_multi'].sort( key=lambda element: int(element[0].replace(' ', '')))
```

И у вас получится в `a`:

```
({'row_n': 1, 'row_section': None, 'nomenclature_name': 'Name', 'article': 'none', 'size_measures_multi': [('1', 'm3', 'brutto'), ('213', 'm', 'netto_brutto_unknown'), ('3454', 'cm3', 'netto_brutto_unknown')]}, {'row_n': 2, 'row_section': None, 'nomenclature_name': 'AIR BAG', 'article': '569002B000WK', 'size_measures_multi': [('2', 'cm3', 'netto_brutto_unknown'), ('331', 'cm3', 'netto_brutto_unknown'), ('3 000', 'cm3', 'netto_brutto_unknown')]})
```

Comment: Благодарю. Это решило проблему.